# Recover emails from unused legacy exchange server

Tags: exchange-2003, data-recovery

I've been presented with an old MS Exchange 2003 server which contains a lot of important emails.

How would I best recover these emails?

My dream scenario would look something like this:

1. Install program y on old server.
2. Program y locates .xxx files containing users emails.
3. Program y converts .xxx files into separate Outlook .pst-files for importing.

Is something like this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the server bootable? Does the Mailbox Store mount? If so, you could use exmerge to extract the email.

Comment: +1, my thoughts exactly. Why use tools you have to pay for when Exchange has built in ones to do exactly what you need. Assuming this server boots, that is.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Exchange Databases and logs available, you can use `Ontrack PowerControls` to recover data / mailboxes from your DB.
http://www.ontrackpowercontrols.com/solutions/exchange-overview/

Comment: I've used the ontrack tools for DR before. Not that cheap but works really well for this kind of scenario.